# How to animate height of the container relative to its children content?

Tags: flutter, animatedcontainer

I want to animate the height property of the container (AnimatedContainer in code below), but I don't want to set hard numbers like this (height: _visible2 ? **160** : 40.9) because height of this container is otherwise relative to its children content (mainly Text)

```
AnimatedContainer(
  curve: Curves.ease,
  height: _visible2 ? 160 : 40.9,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
  child: AnimatedOpacity(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    opacity: _visible2 ? 1.0 : 0,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _visible2 
          ? setState(() {
            _visible2 = !_visible2;
          })
          : null;
      },
      child: myWidget
    ),
  ),
)
```

Is there a way to animate from zero to relative height (for example height of this container can change in landscape mode due to more room for text to lay itself on the screen) ?

Comment: have you tried not setting a height for the container cause by default the container will have a height relative to its child

Comment: Yes, problem is solely with animating it, because if I don't set hard numbers - animation simply will not work.

Comment: You can also use other widgets or build one your own. Check these out: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9uHB8VXZOg